# Подсчитать сумму всех значений в определенном столбце таблицы html

Tags: javascript, html

Таблица - 3 колонки, как на JS подсчитать сумму значений в 3 столбце?

```html
<table id='tab'>
    <tr><td>Наименование</td><td>3</td><td>120</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Наименование</td><td>7</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Наименование</td><td>8</td><td>5250</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let table = document.getElementById("tab");
let sumVal = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  sumVal += parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
}

console.log(sumVal);
```

```html
<table id='tab'>
  <tr>
    <td>Наименование</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Наименование</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Наименование</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>5250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Можно, конечно, собрать данные из ячеек в массив и использовать **[reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**, если хочется. Правда тогда получится два цикла, вместо одного. Но, как вариант...